# (AngularJS) Make a "ng-show" true specifically for one element in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'am begining in Angular, and i'am asking if is it possible to make a "ng-show" true for one element in a "ng-repeat", and make it false for others?

I explain myself with this code:

html file :

```
      <tbody ng-repeat="elem in List"  ng-init="visible = false">
                    <tr ng-class="elemSelected(elem)">
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <a href ng-click="clickElemScroll(Elem)"   >
                            <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="visible? 'glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon-chevron-right'"></span>
                            <strong>{{elem.name}} </strong>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="visible" >
                      blabla
                    </tr>
</tbody>
```

js file :

```
  $scope.clickElemScroll = function (elem) {
                    if ($scope.elemSelected === elem) {
                        $scope.visible = true
                    } 
                };
```

As you know, the issue is all the elem will be scrolled, how to make only the element which I click visible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a new property onto the element to use in the ngRepeat. Also, not sure what is going on with ng-class but I don't recommend using a function in there. If you are trying to set a class when selected, try something like `ng-class="{'selected': elem.selected}"`

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="elem in List">
        <tr ng-class="elemSelected(elem)">
             <td colspan="3">
                  <a href ng-click="elem.selected = !elem.selected">
                     <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="visible? 'glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon-chevron-right'"></span>
                        <strong>{{elem.name}} </strong>
                  </a>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="elem.selected">
             blabla
        </tr>
```

Comment: Hi great thanks for your answer it work ! :)
Now I have a second question, is it possible to make others elements close (!elem.selected for all elem) when I click on an element (only this one has to be open so equals to true ?

Comment: I have a second question, is it possible to make others elements closed (!elem.selected for all elem except the selected) when I click on an element (only this one has to be open)?

Comment: that would be a little different implementation. you would need to make the ng-click a function and do a for loop to go through each elem and set it either unselected or selected. in an ngRepeat you can get the current index of an item anywhere inside the element with `$index`. So, if you wanted to close the other ones your ng-click would be something like `ng-click="setSelected($index)"` and your controller would define that function. In the function do a for loop over List and do something like `List[i].selected = (i === $index);`

Comment: Also, please accept my answer for future people who need help with this

Comment: Finally that is the solution to my issue :
   
 $scope.setSelected = function(elem,index) {

  elem.selected = !elem.selected;

                    for (var i=0;i<$scope.List.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (i!=index)
                            $scope.elem[i].selected = false;

                    }
}

Thanks again @Ero !